# cminer service not autostarting

Tags: service, systemctl, cgminer

I'm trying to set up cgminer as a service and make it autostart after boot. The service run fine if I start it myself, but won't autostart after reboot. I'm using Armbian Ubuntu 18.03 Orange Pi Pc.

The start-mine script looks as following:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/bluudz/git/vthoang/cgminer/
DISPLAY=:0 ./cgminer --config miner.conf
```

and the 
cgminer.service

```
[Unit]
Description=cgminer
After=network.target
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=bluudz

ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -LdmS cgminer /home/bluudz/start-miner
ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -S cgminer -X 'q'
ExecReload=/usr/bin/screen-S cgminer -X stuff "scy'
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Anyone can advice me on what could be done to get the service run on the boot? I have tried for few hours no matter what the service won't start.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was:

```
After=graphical.target
```

The Armbian is running without GUI so it would not start waiting for it.
Removing this sorted it out.